# Как перевести "belief" в философском смысле

Tags: перевод

Как принято переводить философское понятия "belief" на русский язык?

Описания этого термина из Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy:

> Contemporary Anglophone philosophers of mind generally use the term “belief” to refer to the attitude we have, roughly, whenever we take something to be the case or regard it as true. To believe something, in this sense, needn’t involve actively reflecting on it: Of the vast number of things ordinary adults believe, only a few can be at the fore of the mind at any single time. Nor does the term “belief”, in standard philosophical usage, imply any uncertainty or any extended reflection about the matter in question (as it sometimes does in ordinary English usage). Many of the things we believe, in the relevant sense, are quite mundane: that we have heads, that it’s the 21st century, that a coffee mug is on the desk.

Интересно, что у https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belief нет ссылки на русскую версию.

Comment: http://www.harc.ru/slovar/344.html

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! In general, words, especially defining abstract concepts, do not have translations. At best, you might find a Russian word whose meaning in some particular context overlaps with the meaning of the English word. "Belief" is one of these words. You translate texts, not words. If you could provide a Russian phrase with a blank to fill with the word you're looking for, you would probably get a better answer. Thanks!

Comment: зато есть ссылка на версию украинскую - и перевод русскоязычного человека не удивит. Я в принципе считаю, что без объяснения, почему вам кажется, что общепринятый термин "вера" недостаточно хорош для перевода  - этот вопрос стоило бы закрыть.

Comment: Если обратиться к контексту (глава 'What is it to believe?' оттуда же): _When someone learns a particular fact, for example, when Kai reads that astronomers no longer classify Pluto as a planet, he acquires a **new belief** (in this case, the belief that astronomers no longer classify Pluto as a planet)._ Можно предположить, что belief понимается здесь как **представление (о чём-либо)** (=сведения, которые усвоены и не ставятся под сомнение). https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/belief/#WhatItBeli

Comment: Here's an article (Проблемы перевода эпистомологической терминологии /на материале русскоязычных переводов английской философии нового времени/). It includes the term _belief_ (orig. _beleefe_) found in works by Hobbes, Locke and Hume. https://dspace.spbu.ru/bitstream/11701/3534/1/vkr_ustimova_%282%29.docx IMO, the mentioned Russian translations _доверие, вера_ only work in a suitable context.

Answer (score 2):

In philosophy, there is a common definition that knowledge is a justified true **belief**. Searching for the beginning of this phrase "обоснованное истинное" on Google, provides some options for translating "belief".

- обоснованное истинное **мнение**
- обоснованное истинное **убеждение**
- (реже) истинное обоснованное **верование**

"Вера" is only one type of "belief" which is accepted without proof. It seems to be too narrow.

Perhaps I should use "мнение или убеждение" to convey the breadth of the concept.

Comment: "истинное обоснованное верование" - это же нонсенс :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, "belief/beliefs" are translated as "убеждение/убеждения".

"Вера" is applicable in case of "religious beliefs".